# How to explode the dataset in JSON file by using explode functionality in R?

Tags: r, apache-spark, nested, explode, sparklyr

**Note** - I have referred [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52194942/10321971), but although the data is un-nested but I could not convert data into csv file format.

**I want to flatten the data of different data types by using explode functionality**. The dataset contains arrays and structure. I want to explode the data so that I can further convert it into CSV file format.

**Introduction**

R code is written by using Sparklyr package to create database schema. *[Reproducible code and database is given]*

**Existing Result**

```
root
|-- contributors : string
|-- created_at : string
|-- entities (struct)
|     |-- hashtags (array) : [string]
|     |-- media (array)
|     |     |-- additional_media_info (struct)
|     |     |       |-- description : string
|     |     |       |-- embeddable : boolean
|     |     |       |-- monetizable : bollean
|     |     |-- diplay_url : string
|     |     |-- id : long
|     |     |-- id_str : string
|     |-- urls (array)     
|-- extended_entities (struct)
|-- retweeted_status (struct)
|-- user (struct)
```

I want to flatten this structure as below,

**Expected Result**

```
root
|-- contributors : string
|-- created_at : string
|-- entities (struct)
|-- entities.hashtags (array) : [string]
|-- entities.media (array)
|-- entities.media.additional_media_info (struct)
|-- entities.media.additional_media_info.description : string
|-- entities.media.additional_media_info.embeddable : boolean
|-- entities.media.additional_media_info.monetizable : bollean
|-- entities.media.diplay_url : string
|-- entities.media.id : long
|-- entities.media.id_str : string
|-- entities.urls (array)     
|-- extended_entities (struct)
|-- retweeted_status (struct)
|-- user (struct)
```

**Database**  Navigate to: 
[Data-0.5 MB](https://pastebin.com/Shggpn04) . Then copy the numbered items to a text file named "example". Save to a directory named "../example.json/" created in your working directory.

The R code is written to reproduce the example as below,

**Exiting Code**

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
library(devtools)
  devtools::install_github("mitre/sparklyr.nested")
# If Spark is not installed, then also need:
# spark_install(version = "2.2.0")
library(sparklyr.nested)
library(testthat)
library(jsonlite)

Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/usr/lib/spark")    
conf <- spark_config()
conf$'sparklyr.shell.executor-memory' <- "20g"
conf$'sparklyr.shell.driver-memory' <- "20g"
conf$spark.executor.cores <- 16
conf$spark.executor.memory <- "20G"
conf$spark.yarn.am.cores  <- 16
conf$spark.yarn.am.memory <- "20G"
conf$spark.executor.instances <- 8
conf$spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled <- "false"
conf$maximizeResourceAllocation <- "true"
conf$spark.default.parallelism <- 32
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", config = conf, version = '2.2.0') # Connection             
 sample_tbl <- spark_read_json(sc,name="example",path="example.json", header = TRUE, memory = FALSE, overwrite = TRUE) 
 sdf_schema_viewer(sample_tbl) # to create db schema
```

**I want to flatten the data of different data types by using explode functionality. Please don't use another package because my 1 billion data is not readable by using other than Sparklyr package. Sparklyr package only read this huge data within few minutes.**

**Goal** - Further I want this exploded data to convert into proper csv file format.

Answer (score 3):

In short you two requirements:

- Expected schema.
- I want this un-nested data to convert into proper csv file format.

Are not compatible. CSV reader cannot handle complex types including `arrays`, for which clearly ask in this and the previous questions.

To fully satisfy the second requirement you'll have to use one of the following

- Serialize array and structs, for example using JSON
- Fully explode dataset, including top level array fields, to achieve tidy format.This will however significantly increase the amount of data as for each record you'll get `length(hashtags) * length(media) * length(urls)` rows.