# I want to flatten a Nested Json File using Spark Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

My File looks like this

```
{
    "Item Version": 1.0,
    "Item Creation Time": "2019-04-14 14:15:09",
    "Trade Dictionary": {
        "Country": "India",
        "TradeNumber": "1",
        "action": {
            "Action1": false
        },
        "Value": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    "Payments": {
        "Payment Details": [{
            "Payment Date": "2019-04-11",
            "Payment Type": "Rej"
        }]
    }
}
```

I want the result in below format

```
Item Version,Item Creation Time,Trade Dictionary.Country,Trade Dictionary.TradeNumber,Trade Dictionary.TradeNumber.action.Action1,Trade Dictionary.TradeNumber.value,Payment.Payment Details.Payment Date,Payment.Payment Details.Payment Type
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You can take a look at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45178338/create-a-spark-dataframe-from-a-nested-json-file-in-scala

Comment: This question duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851002