# How to convert a list of maps into maps in Scala?

Tags: scala, list

I have a `Map` like this:

```scala
val map: Map[String, Any] = Map(
  "Item Version" -> 1.0,
  "Item Creation Time" -> "2019-04-14 14:15:09",
  "Trade Dictionary" -> Map(
    "Country" -> "India",
    "TradeNumber" -> "1",
    "action" -> Map(
      "Action1" -> false
    ),
    "Value" -> "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  ),
  "Payments" -> Map(
    "Payment Details" -> List(
      Map(
        "Payment Date" -> "2019-04-11",
        "Payment Type" -> "Rej"
))))
```

I have written a piece of code:

```scala
def flattenMap(map: Map[String, Any]): Map[String, Any] = {
  val c = map.flatten {
    case ((key, map : Map[String, Any])) => map
    case ((key, value)) => Map(key -> value)
    // case ((key, List(map))) =>
  }.toMap
  return c
}

def secondFlatten(map: Map[String, Any]): Map[String, Any] = {
  val c=map.flatten {
    case ((key, map : Map[String, Any])) => flattenMap(map)
    case ((key, value)) => Map(key -> value)
  }.toMap

  return c 
}
```

Which gives output like this:

```
(Country, India)
(Action1, false)
(Value, XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
(Item Version, 1.0)
(TradeNumber, 1)
(Item Creation Time, 2019-04-14 14:15:09)
(Payment Details, List(Map(Payment Date -> 2019-04-11, Payment Type -> Rej)))
```

I want make some code changes in which I can convert the list of maps to a map like the output, i.e. instead of `(Payment Details,List(Map(Payment Date -> 2019-04-11, Payment Type -> Rej)))`, I should get:

```
(Payment Date , 2019-04-11), 
(Payment Type , Rej)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle your list of map. Based on example you provided, I've updated your method to this:

```
def secondFlatten(map: Map[String, Any]):Map[String, Any]={
 map.flatten {
   case ((key, map : Map[String, Any])) => {
     map.flatten {
       case ((key: String, l: List[Map[String, Any]])) => l.head
       case ((key: String, m : Map[String, Any])) => m
       case (key: String, value: String) => Map(key -> value)
     }
   }
   case ((key, value)) => Map(key -> value)
 }.toMap
}
```

This might be something that might be useful for your question in the comment. It appends all keys together and keeps value in the map. You could further extend it should you need more complex solution:

```
  def secondFlatten(map: Map[String, Any]):Map[String, Any]={
   map.flatten {
     case ((key, map : Map[String, Any])) => {
       map.flatten {
         case ((innerKey: String, l: List[Map[String, Any]])) => l.head.map{case (x:String, y: Any)=> (s"$key--$innerKey--$x"-> y)}
         case ((innerKey: String, m : Map[String, Any])) => m.map{case (x:String, y: Any)=> (s"$key--$innerKey--$x"-> y)}
         case (innerKey: String, value: String) => Map(s"$key--$innerKey"-> value)
    }
  }
  case ((key, value)) => Map(key -> value)
}.toMap
```

}

Comment: Can you suggest any way I can add the prefix names here in the code like instaed of (Action1,false) it should print  (Trade Dictionary_action_Action1)??

Answer (score 0):

For your particular case you can update your `flattenMap` method:

```scala
def flattenMap(map: Map[String, Any]): Map[String, Any] = {
  val c = map.flatten {
    case ((key, map : Map[String, Any])) => map
    case ((key, value)) => Map(key -> value)
    case ((key, map :: Nil)) => map
  }.toMap
  return c
}
```

If you want to handle a list of multiple maps, you should probably wrap your returned values into lists and so use some kind of `flatMap` instead of `toMap`.

Comment: I am gettting type miss match error           case ((key, map :: Nil)) => map